# Default value within data validation given data in cell

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to get to display the default value of a data validation list on a cell contingent on the value (city in this example) input on a different cell.

Data and sample below:

[image]

For example, when I am filling-in the name and city of residence of someone in Madrid, I would like that cell "B3" to display the "Default Language" as specified in "Default Table".

Guidance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: you could add `=vlookup(...)` function within B3 cell.

Comment: @KazJaw, macutan wants data validation, but wants it to default to appropriate language.

Comment: I don't have time to work on this now, but you need a `Worksheet_Change` event that has a coded `VLookup`. When the cell with the City name changes then change the value in the Mother Tongue cell, using a `VLookup` in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Prerequisites
'Select the City range (from Madrid to Pontevedra) and name it rngCity using Formulas > Define Name
'Select the Language range (from Spanish to Gallician) and name it rngLanguage using Formulas > Define Name

Dim dblFind As Double

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then 'Detects if B2 has changed
    dblFind = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("B2").Value, Range("rngCity"), 0)
    Range("B3").Value = Range("rngLanguage").Cells(dblFind)
End If

End Sub
```